# Rendering a component inside another component not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component called "contactList" and i want to render it inside of another component called "App" but it gives me an error that say "contactList is defined but never used  no-unused-vars"

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class contactList extends Component {
  render(){
    const people = [
      {name: "kester"},
      {name: "john"},
      {name: "mary"}
    ]

     return <ol>
      {people.map(person =>(
        <li key={person.name}>{person.name}</li>
      ))}
     </ol>
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return <div className='App'>
    <contactList/>
  </div>
      
    
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: react components should start with capital letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React component name must start with capital letter.

So, you need to rename your `conatctList` component with `ContactList`.

Answer (score 1):

When running your code, I get the following error:

```
Warning: <%s /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.%s
contactList

    at contactList
    at div
    at App (<anonymous>:51:11)
```

Rename your component to `ContactList` and update the usage to `<ContactList/>`